# How to delete characters out of a variable in php

Tags: php, html, variables

It's pretty straight forward. Currently I need to delete the first 12 characters out of variable `$mess[1]` but it seems like all of the commands I find are centered towards deleting it by phrase. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php), which returns a new string, so just assign that new string to your variable...

```
$everythingExceptTheFirstTwelveCharacters = substr($str, 12);
```

Comment: +1 Love the variable name ;)

Comment: shouldn't it be `substr($str, 11);` since `substr()` is zero based?

Comment: thank you sir, the actual amount of subtraction is based off of a variable, so the actual integer used is not too big of a deal.

Comment: @eskimo Seems to work out for me.

Comment: my mistake actually, `substr($str, 0);` would return the full string

Answer (score 2):

If, by chance, you are using multi-byte character encodings, or you get that as a result, you can instead use the multi-byte version of mb_substr.  It will work for multi-byte and single-byte strings.  http://php.net/mb_substr

Use 11 as the first character position is 0.

```
$mess[1] = mb_substr($mess[1],11);
```

Comment: *Use 11 as the first character position is 0.*, so the first character of the new string will be the twelfth of the input string?

Answer (score 1):

```
 $mess[1] = substr($mess[1],12)
```